# How to get around the 50k input message limit in a Sumo Logic join?

Tags: log-analysis, sumologic

I'm parsing our production logs and need to "join" 2 log lines, one containing an IP the other a user ID, and both have a request ID to join on. This is to compare and count and detect users signin from multiple IP and IPs used by multiple users.

It looks like the [join operator](https://help.sumologic.com/docs/search/search-query-language/search-operators/join/) is the way to do this, and I got it working for small time ranges, unfortunately it has a 50000 input message limit which is really little and makes it quite useless for production traffic. I tried using `timewindow` to limit how far the system needs to search in logs but that doesn't seem to change anything.

I don't think I'm doing something particularly rare, matching IP from an access log (which often has millions of lines/day) with another log line so I'm surprised by the very low limit on this. Is there some other way to achieve the same result in Sumo Logic?